# Run Custom Tflite Model in Flutter | Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'CONV_2D' version '5'

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite

I am working on a flutter app that uses a custom Tflite Model based on the Densenet Architecture.

Currently I am trying to get the Model running in my App.

Model Input:

- (224,224,3) RGB image in float format in range [0, 255.0] with Imagenet pre-processing.

Output:

- two channels output, this is a probability output.
- Index of higher value represents the pixels of the leaf.
- Then, this output is converted to uint8 for the mask generation.

I tried the tflite.dart Package and the tflite_flutter Package

While using tflite.dart Packag, my App crashes when I am trying to use the runModelonBinary-Method from the Package.

```
  var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnBinary(
      binary: imageToByteListFloat32(image, 224, 127.5, 127.5),// required
      numResults: 6,    // defaults to 5
      threshold: 0.05,  // defaults to 0.1
      asynch: true      // defaults to true
    );
    
    Uint8List imageToByteListFloat32(
        img.Image image, int inputSize, double mean, double std) {
      var convertedBytes = Float32List(1 * inputSize * inputSize * 3);
      var buffer = Float32List.view(convertedBytes.buffer);
      int pixelIndex = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < inputSize; j++) {
          var pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);
          buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getRed(pixel) - mean) / std;
          buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getGreen(pixel) - mean) / std;
          buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getBlue(pixel) - mean) / std;
        }
      }
      return convertedBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
    }
    
    Uint8List imageToByteListUint8(img.Image image, int inputSize) {
      var convertedBytes = Uint8List(1 * inputSize * inputSize * 3);
      var buffer = Uint8List.view(convertedBytes.buffer);
      int pixelIndex = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < inputSize; j++) {
          var pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);
          buffer[pixelIndex++] = img.getRed(pixel);
          buffer[pixelIndex++] = img.getGreen(pixel);
          buffer[pixelIndex++] = img.getBlue(pixel);
        }
      }
      return convertedBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
    }
```

When I try to use ute tflite_flutter Package to create an Inference Pipeline

```
 Uint8List model = await _createModelFromAsset(path);
 Interpreter interpreter = Interpreter.fromBuffer(model);
```

I run into this Error:

```
Didn't find op for builtin opcode 'CONV_2D' version '5'
```

1. Is it possible to run custom Models with the tflite.dart package?
2. What causes the error above and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Conv2D version 5 is supported by TensorFlow Lite 2.4.0 or above, which was released in Dec 2020.

You can try to update the version of the TensorFlow Lite runtime. However the Flutter/Dart packages are not officially supported but contributed by the community, so I'm unsure if there's a build for 2.4.0 or newer.